# GLSL: Issue replacing ternary operator with mix

Tags: shaders, glsl, fragment-shader

I was expecting these two code snippets to do the same thing:

```
return  vec3(  1.0-b.r>=a.r ? 0.0 : 1.0-((1.0-b.r)/a.r),
               1.0-b.g>=a.g ? 0.0 : 1.0-((1.0-b.g)/a.g),
               1.0-b.b>=a.b ? 0.0 : 1.0-((1.0-b.b)/a.b)  );
```

and

```
return mix( ONE3 - ((ONE3-b)/a), ZERO3, vec3(greaterThanEqual(ONE3-b, a)) ); 
       // ONE3=vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0); ZERO3=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
```

For some reason, they have different outputs. Do you know why? (`a` can have zeros sometimes)

Comment: Rather than saying "I think it will perform faster", why not profile your code, determine if your current approach actually *is* a performance problem, then determine if your alternate approach actually *will* perform faster first?

Comment: I will profile my code. But now I am trying to find out, why they behave differently, when they are logically the same.

Comment: What you mean by different outputs? 4 insted of 5, or 4.000001 instead of 4.000002?

Comment: I am using it to combine pixels of two textures and the output color is a lot different ... so like 4 instead of 5.

Comment: @IvanKuckir TL;DR: you're getting NaN from the divisions by zero and mix doesn't like it. Longer answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that `(ONE3-b)/a` may cause a division by zero. This causes the result to be NaN (Not A Number). In that case mix will also return NaN because pretty much anything done to a NaN gives back an NaN and `mix(a, b, i)` internally does `a*(1-i) + b*i` or `a + (b-a)*i`.

try using `mix( ONE3 - ((ONE3-b)/max(a, vec3(0.001, 0.001, 0.001))), ZERO3, step(a, ONE3-b) );`

Using `max(a, tiny_value )` prevents a division by zero.

Using `?:` avoids the NaN case completely.

And instead of `greaterThanEqual` and a cast back to `vec3` you can use `step(edge, x)` which returns 0 if x < edge and 1 otherwise without branching.

You should really profile your shaders on the target platform. Depending on the GPU and the operands used sometimes `?:` will be faster.

Some GPUs (especially mobile GPUs) don't mind branches too much and may benefit from them if the calculation skipped is quite long.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Zero times NaN is not Zero, but NaN.

Comment: BTW. I am doing it in WebGL, which may run on different desktop and mobile devices, so it is hard to profile. But I am sure it will not be the bottleneck of my app, so I will use the mix() version, because it is shorter.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about step() ! Is there also an alternative for vec3(equal(b,ONE3)) ?

Comment: @IvanKuckir: Yes, but it may not be faster. make sure to profile this on different GPUs: `(vec3(1,1,1) - abs(sign(b - vec3(1,1,1))))`

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually need `mix`. Just realise that `1.0-(1.0-b)/(1.0-b)` is always zero (except in the case of a division by zero, we’ll come to that later).

So you can just forget the ternary operator and when `1.0-b>=a`, instead of dividing by `a` you just divide by `1-b` to get zero in the end. This means dividing by `max(1-b,a)`:

```
vec3 m = max(ONE3 - b, a);
return ONE3 - (ONE3 - b) / m;
```

This can be rewritten as:

```
vec3 m = max(ONE3 - b, a);
return (m + b - ONE3) / m;
```

Now you still have a division by zero when `b` is exactly `1` and `a` is exactly `0`. This can be prevented using a small correcting factor:

```
vec3 m = max(ONE3 - b, a);
return (m + b - ONE3) / max(m, vec3(1e-6));
```